# Determining Whether Graph G = (V,E) Contains a Negative-Weight Cycle

Tags: java

In this program, I am given an input text file that gives information about a weighted, directed graph

> G = (V, E, w)

The first line of the text file in input stores `V` (the number of vertices) and `E` (the number of edges).

The following lines store data about edges (`u`, `v`) in order `u`, `v`, weight.

I'm trying to implement a code that considers this input and determines whether `G` contains a negative-weight cycle.

So far, I've tried to use the *Bellman Ford algorithm* to try to get this to work: I started by initializing a `dist[]` array that initializes distances from the source to all other vertices as some really high number (making sure src to src is 0).

Next, I relax all edges `|V| - 1` times.

Finally, I check for negative-weight cycles by iterating through the array of edges again, checking to see if we get a shorter path.

However, when I try to do that second step of relaxing the edges, I keep getting an index out of bounds error.

**NOTE: To examine the code below, just scroll down to the method isNegativeCycle(). I just included some of the other stuff in case anyone needs background information.**

```
public class P1 {
//instance variables
static int V;   //number of vertices
static int E;   //number of edges

//vertex class
public class Vertex {
    int ID; //the name of the vertex
}

//edge class
public class Edge {
    Vertex source;  //the source vertex - its a directed graph
    Vertex dest;    //the destination vertex
    int weight; //the weight of the edge
}


//graph class where all the magic happens
public class Graph { 
    //Each graph has an array of edges
    Edge edgearray[];

    //constructor
    public Graph(int n, int m)  {
        V = n;
        E = m;

        edgearray = new Edge[E];
        for (int i = 0; i < E; i++) { 
            edgearray[i] = new Edge();
        }
    }

    //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT METHOD
    public String isNegativeCycle(Graph G, int src) {
        int dist[] = new int[V];
        Arrays.fill(dist, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        dist[src] = 0;  //cos the distance from A to A is 0

        //Relax all edges
        for (int i = 1; i <= V-1; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < E; j++) { 
                int u = G.edgearray[j].source.ID; 
                int v = G.edgearray[j].dest.ID; 
                int weight = G.edgearray[j].weight; 

            //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS ERROR    
            if (dist[u]!= Integer.MAX_VALUE && (dist[u]+weight) < dist[v]) { 
                    dist[v] = dist[u]+weight; 
            } 
        } 

        //check for a negative cycle
        for (int a = 0; a < E; a++) { 
            int u = G.edgearray[a].source.ID; 
            int v = G.edgearray[a].dest.ID; 
                double weight = G.edgearray[a].weight;

                if (dist[u] != Integer.MAX_VALUE && dist[u]+weight < dist[v])   {
                return "YES";
            }
        } 


        return "NO";
    }


}//end of graph class


//main method 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    P1 instance = new P1();
    int n;
    int m;
    int counter = 0;
    boolean fl = true;
    String infileName = args[0];
    Graph G = instance.new Graph(V, E);

    File infile = new File(infileName);
    Scanner fileReader = null;
    try {
        fileReader = new Scanner(infile);
        while (fileReader.hasNextLine())    {

            //if we're reading the first line
            if (fl == true) {
                String[] temp = fileReader.nextLine().split(" ");
                n = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
                V = n;
                m = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
                E = m;
                G = instance.new Graph(V, E);
                fl = false;
            }
            //if we're reading any line other than the first line
            else    {
                String[] temp = fileReader.nextLine().split(" ");
                //G.addEdge(temp[0], temp[1], Double.parseDouble(temp[2]));

                Vertex newsrc = instance.new Vertex();
                Vertex newdest = instance.new Vertex();

                newsrc.ID = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
                newdest.ID = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);

                Edge newEdge = instance.new Edge();
                newEdge.source = newsrc;
                newEdge.dest = newdest;
                newEdge.weight = Integer.parseInt(temp[2]);

                G.edgearray[counter] = newEdge;
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");  
    }

    System.out.println(G.isNegativeCycle(G, 0));
}
}
```

My current input file doesn't really matter at this point, but after this code runs, I expect the output to be "YES." Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've included my input file. In my input file, you would see that the vertex names start at 1. Thus, when calling `isNegativeCycle`, I shoudl've sent in a 1 instead of a 0. In addition, I make the `dist[]` array one size bigger.